# cant echo all option in selenium

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I can not get all my options in selenium webdriver
my select sample HTML : 
http://webnabsh.com/sele/hi.html
And my get php webdrive sample : 
http://webnabsh.com/sele/index.php
code :

```
$select = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('xcv'));
//$select->click();

//echo $select->getAttribute('data-trigger');
# get all the options for this element
$allOptions = $select->findElement(WebDriverBy::tagName('option'));
foreach ($allOptions as $option){

  echo "Value is:" . $option->getAttribute("value");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
$allOptions = $select->findElement(WebDriverBy::tagName('option'));
```

only returns one web element because you're using `findElement`. It returns the first option it finds, so in your case 'Volvo'.

Change it to `findElements` to get all the options:

```
$allOptions = $select->findElements(WebDriverBy::tagName('option'));
```

Comment: Nice, glad to help